# using mappings in order to reduce k-SUM to k-clique

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reductions

In page $4$ of this [paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/MatchTria.pdf), **Lemma 2.1** claims to establish a reduction from $k$-$SUM$ to $k$-$Clique$ problem:

> For any integers $n,c,d,p \geq 1$ such that $p ≥ 3n^{\lceil
> > c/d\rceil}$, there is a set of $s = 2^{o(d)}$ mappings
>   $f_1,\cdots,f_s:[−n^c, n^c] → [−p/3, p/3]^d$ and $s$ target vectors
>   $t_1,\cdots,t_s \in [−p,p]^d$ such that:
>
> For every $x,y,z \in [−n^c,n^c]$,
>   $$x+y+z = 0 \iff \exists i\in[s].f_i(x) + f_i(y) + f_i(z) = t_i$$.

There are two things I do not quite get about this:

1. How does this establishes the reduction,
2. And, what is the role of the condition: $p\geq 3n^{\lceil\frac{c}d\rceil}$?

---

**EDIT**: It should be noted that the original source for this lemma is: **Lemma 3.1** of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3054.pdf).

Comment: Where was it suggested?  Please credit your sources. Please provide a citation/reference for where you saw it.  Can you provide additional context?  You might need to ask whoever made that suggestion to you why they think it is relevant.  For your second question, you have been given a claim.   Have you tried to prove the claim?  I suggest you first check whether that proof uses the condition you mention; if so, that answers your second question.  I encourage you to edit your question to include this information.

Comment: The paper tells you why it is relevant.  It suggests that the reduction goes through an intermediate problem, EW-Triangle.  Immediately after that lemma it says "The basic idea is..."  The paper then proceeds to give the full reduction.  The paper also gives a citation where the Lemma comes from, so you should go read that paper.  You should read all of that carefully.  Also, the paper mentions a "full version".  You should contact the authors to ask if you can get a copy of the full version. I think you should exhaust these obvious avenues on your own before asking someone here to help you.